# How can I know the open/closed status of an Excel file from Visual Basic

Tags: file-io, vb6

I'm working in Visual Basic 6. I opened an Excel file from vb6 command and then closed it. Now I want to get the file status. How can know that file is closed or opened?  Please give me the syntex of getting the open or closed status of a certain file from Visual Basic 6. OR in other words, i opened a file of excel through vb santax then again i open the same file then there should be response that this file is already opended please select another one.

Answer (score 3):

How about [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1572054&page=26):

```
Option Explicit

Private Function FileStatus(ByVal FileName As String) As VbTriState
    Dim intFile As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    GetAttr FileName
    If Err.Number Then
        FileStatus = vbUseDefault 'File doesn't exist or file server not available.
    Else
        Err.Clear
        intFile = FreeFile(0)
        Open FileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #intFile
        If Err.Number Then
            FileStatus = vbFalse 'File already open.
        Else
            Close #intFile
            FileStatus = vbTrue 'File available and not open by anyone.
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Sub cmdGetStatus_Click()
    Select Case FileStatus(txtFileName.Text)
        Case vbUseDefault
            MsgBox "File doesn't exist or file server not available"
        Case vbFalse
            MsgBox "File already open"
        Case vbTrue
            MsgBox "File available and not open by anyone"
    End Select
End Sub
```